# Advice on mathematical and physical sources & dictionaries with the indexes (filters)

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, advice, online-resources

Could you recommend some resources or dictionaries on mathematics and physics with terms filtered by thematic indexes, such as the Compendium of Chemistry Terminology (a.k.a. the IUPAC Gold Book) or thesaurus.maths.org?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean https://plus.maths.org/content/tags/thesaurus?

Comment: Yes, I did. However, the http://thesaurus.maths.org/ source doesn't exist on the Internet. That's why I'm writing about this unsolved problem.